# Record data to proper html children elements when cloning

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, append, clone

I have a form in Google sheets where I send dynamic data from the sheet.

I loop sheet data and create same number of blocks in a form as number of my headers.

I have a first block of elements written in html.
The rest of blocks I clone from the first one, clone its IDs and send my sheet titles to  elements of the form.

First title I write (with the last title from an array) to the only block existing before looping.

Then I clone that block giving a clone new titles and trying to insert clones before the first block ([0]) but it gets wrong and **overwrites my first hardcoded title**.

**It appends the blocks in random number, so I can't get my titles in the right sequence like "1,2,3".**
It's always like "2,1,1" or "1,3,2" etc.

I've tried different variations of appending the cloned elements (like `motherDiv.appendChild(clonedRow)` and `motherDiv.insertBefore(clonedRow, motherDiv.children[0])`, but cannot get it to work properly.

Please point to what's wrong here.

Here's the code and the screen:

```js
//my google app backend function with data    
var numbers = [1, 2, 3]
var stats = ["Валовый доход", "Кол-во клиентов", "Кол-во размещенной рекламы"]

var stats = {

  statNumbers: numbers,
  statStats: stats
}



//select initialization
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var getstats = getStats();
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
  var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
});


//getting stats object
function getStats() {

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(processStats).statsObj();
  google.script.run.withFailureHandler(showError).statsObj()

  return;
}


//creating dynamic stats fields in the form
function processStats(stats) {

  //name first statistic with the last number
  var firstStat = document.getElementById("statName").innerHTML = stats.statNumbers[stats.statStats.length - 1] + ". " + stats.statStats[stats.statStats.length - 1]

  //mother div
  var motherDiv = document.getElementById("motherDiv")

  //sample row to copy
  var statRow = document.getElementById("statsample");

  //loop stat names
  for (var i = 0; i < stats.statStats.length - 1; i++) {

    var statName = stats.statStats[i]
    var statNumber = stats.statNumbers[i]

    //cloning the original row
    var clonedRow = statRow.cloneNode(true)

    //setting unique ID to whole row
    var rowId = clonedRow.id = "statsample" + i

    //setting unique ID to stat div
    var clonedStatID = motherDiv.getElementsByClassName("statClass")[0].id = "statName" + statNumber

    //stat titles (except first one)
    var statHtml = document.getElementById(clonedStatID).innerHTML = statNumber + ". " + statName;

    var err = document.getElementById("err").innerHTML = motherDiv.children.length

    //appending it to the mother div
    //motherDiv.appendChild(clonedRow);
    motherDiv.insertBefore(clonedRow, motherDiv.children[0]);

  }
  return;
}



function showError() {

  var err = document.getElementById("err").innerHTML = "There was an error."
}
```

```html
<!--Import Google Icon Font-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<div id="motherDiv">
  <!-- mother div -->

  <div class="row" id="statsample">

    <div class=" input-field col s3 #fffde7 yellow lighten-5">
      <h6 id="statName" class="statClass"></h6>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field col s3">
      <select class="icons browser-default" id="weeksSel4">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Неделя</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field col s2">
      <input id="numbers" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="numbers">Значение</label>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field col s1.5">
      <select class="icons browser-default" id="measure">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Ед. изм:</option>
        <option value="">шт.</option>
        <option value="">%</option>
        <option value="">$</option>
        <option value="">руб.</option>
        <option value="">грн.</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field col s2.5">
      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small #039be5 light-blue darken-1" style="float: right;" id="btn1row"><i class="material-icons right">send</i>Ввести</a>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- row end -->
</div>
<!-- mother div end-->

<div id="err"> </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Why exactly are you populating the 'master' div **statsample** with the values from the last element inside the array and try to append the clones before? I'd say simply give the master the data from the first element of the array and the clones the rest.

Comment: I tried both directions: starting from the first etc and starting from the last and append before: in all variants I tried it appends rows in such random order and I never get 1, 2, 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend populating the 'master' div with the first element of the array and for the clones start iterating over the array from index 1.
We need to make some fundamental changes to your `processStats(stats)` function.
First populate the master:

```
  var firstStat = document.getElementById("statName").innerHTML = stats.statNumbers[0] + ". " + stats.statStats[0];
```

the following two lines are untouched

```
  var motherDiv = document.getElementById("motherDiv")
  var statRow = document.getElementById("statsample");
```

Change the for loop to start from 1

```
  for (var i = 1; i < stats.statStats.length; i++) {
  }
```

Now the for-loop itself needs some changes.
These three lines are okay

```
var statName = stats.statStats[i];
var statNumber = stats.statNumbers[i];
var clonedRow = statRow.cloneNode(true);
```

What I don't understand is the following

```
var clonedStatID = motherDiv.getElementsByClassName("statClass")[0].id = "statName" + statNumber
```

I know you want to give the freshly cloned divs child **statClass** a unique id with a sequential number but with every iteration of the for-loop this would give the first element in the list the id. Above you already have a variable which holds a reference to the cloned div **clonedRow** you can also use to access it's children.

So get rid of the line and use this:

```
clonedRow.getElementsByTagName("h6")[0].innerHTML = statNumber + ". " + statName;
```

Now just append the div to the parent

```
motherDiv.appendChild(clonedRow);
```

Here's a working example - just click 'Run code snippet' to see it in action:

```js
//my google app backend function with data    
var numbers = [1, 2, 3]
var stats = ["Валовый доход", "Кол-во клиентов", "Кол-во размещенной рекламы"]

var stats = {

  statNumbers: numbers,
  statStats: stats
}

function processStats(stats) {

  //name first statistic with the last number
  var firstStat = document.getElementById("statName").innerHTML = stats.statNumbers[0] + ". " + stats.statStats[0];

  //mother div
  var motherDiv = document.getElementById("motherDiv")

  //sample row to copy
  var statRow = document.getElementById("statsample");

  //loop stat names
  for (var i = 1; i < stats.statStats.length; i++) {

    var statName = stats.statStats[i];
    var statNumber = stats.statNumbers[i];
    var clonedRow = statRow.cloneNode(true);
    var rowId = clonedRow.id = "statsample" + i;
    clonedRow.getElementsByTagName("h6")[0].innerHTML = statNumber + ". " + statName;
    var err = document.getElementById("err").innerHTML = motherDiv.children.length
    motherDiv.appendChild(clonedRow);
  }
  return;
}

function showError() {
  var err = document.getElementById("err").innerHTML = "There was an error."
}

processStats(stats);
```

```html
<!--Import Google Icon Font-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<div id="motherDiv">
  <!-- mother div -->

  <div class="row" id="statsample">

    <div class=" input-field col s3 #fffde7 yellow lighten-5">
      <h6 id="statName" class="statClass"></h6>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field col s3">
      <select class="icons browser-default" id="weeksSel4">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Неделя</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field col s2">
      <input id="numbers" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="numbers">Значение</label>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field col s1.5">
      <select class="icons browser-default" id="measure">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Ед. изм:</option>
        <option value="">шт.</option>
        <option value="">%</option>
        <option value="">$</option>
        <option value="">руб.</option>
        <option value="">грн.</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field col s2.5">
      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small #039be5 light-blue darken-1" style="float: right;" id="btn1row"><i class="material-icons right">send</i>Ввести</a>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- row end -->
</div>
<!-- mother div end-->

<div id="err"> </div>
```

Comment: That's amazing, thank you! I see my mistake now. You've completely helped me on this! Now it's all working properly.

Comment: No problem kiki - glad I could help!

Comment: True) could you possibly help with that too? I added comments with new data there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56798076/cannot-get-an-array-of-all-buttons-from-a-form?noredirect=1#comment100162954_56798076