# Cannot get an array of all buttons from a form

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, materialize

I have several buttons on the Google Apps Script HTML Service form in Google Sheets (I use [Materialize](https://materializecss.com/buttons.html) framework). One was written and the rest were cloned from it.

Need to **get an array of all that buttons**, but I failed. It had to show 3 elements in an array, but it shows 1.

This is the original button which I cloned:

```html
<!--Import Google Icon Font-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<div class="input-field col s2.5">

 <!--this is the BUTTON -->
  <a class="buttonClass waves-effect waves-light btn-small #039be5 light-blue darken-1" style="float: right;" id="btnrow"><i class="material-icons right">send</i>Ввести</a>
</div>
```

I am trying to get buttons by class (as the ids are different):

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('buttonClass').length;
```

I am doing this to **get the id or position of the button that were clicked**.

Please let me know if you need me to provide more code. Thanks.

Here's how I cloned elements:

```js
//loop stat names (data from backend)
for (var i = 0; i < stats.statStats.length; i++) {

  var statName = stats.statStats[i]
  var statNumber = stats.statNumbers[i]

  //cloning the original row with all elements
  var clonedRow = statRow.cloneNode(true)

  //setting unique ID to whole row
  var rowId = clonedRow.id = "statsample" + i

  //setting unique ID to stat div
  var clonedStatID = motherDiv.getElementsByClassName("statClass")[0].id = "statName" + statNumber
  //assing stat names
  var statHtml = document.getElementById(clonedStatID).innerHTML = statNumber + ". " + statName;

  motherDiv.insertBefore(clonedRow, motherDiv.children[0]);

}
```

Comment: `var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('buttonClass').length;` This will just assign the length of the HTML collection to the variable `buttons`. If you want to get the actual array get rid of `.length` - If that doesn't fix your problem please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: ok, how to iterate through them then? I do for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) { var button = buttons[i];} And how to see the length?

Comment: I don't see how your freshly posted code is relevant to the question. There's no reference to a buttonClass at all. Can you post a proper example?

Comment: I removed [tag:google-sheets] because the issue isn't related to it, by the other hand I added the [tag:materialize] as it's being used on the code.

Comment: Regarding the proper example requested on a previous comment, please make sure that it's a [mcve]

Comment: buttonClass is just a name of the class (no css for it). You can see it in the first block  where the button is (updated comments). It didin't influence the problem when I took "btn-small" class or other classes.

Comment: @kiki What's the relevance of the last script `Here's how I cloned elements:`? That's what obscure is asking.

Comment: I assume that the problem might be connected to cloning (not assigning a class to cloned elements). Because When I do var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('buttonClass').length I get 1 (the initial button).

Comment: I tried to assign to <a> element (a button) of each newly cloned row a same class: 
 clonedRow.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].classList.add("buttonClass") - but it didn't change things. Still get 1 element of buttonClass instead of 3.